# How to integrate GitHub Actions OIDC with IdentityServer 4?

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm trying to allow GitHub Actions to call my REST API that is protected with IdentityServer4. I take a look on GitHub [docs](https://docs.github.com/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#overview-of-openid-connect) about its OIDC and I understand that I can request for ID Token inside Actions. The question is how to get access token from IdentityServer4 with this ID Token so GitHub Actions can invoke my REST API?

Answer (score 0):

For a client to get a ID-token, then a user must be involved to authorize the client so that you can get the ID/access token. (using the authorization code flow).

A better approach might be to use the client credentials flow, that is used for machine-to-machine communication and you can configure a client definition in IdentityServer that issues an access token to your GitHub action using a simple username/password (client/clientsecret). That is the simplest way to get it to work. In this flow there is no use/need for any ID-token.

see https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/tokens/requesting/#machine-to-machine-communication

Comment: Thanks for information. Unfortunately that is not how OIDC in GitHub Actions work. When a job run inside Actions it can ask GitHub for an ID Token that represent the job without user interaction. The other services like AWS can exchange access token with this token so the customer application that run on AWS can authenticate a job in Actions.

Comment: The challenge is how to get IdentityServer to trust this ID-token that is issued by someone else. You could hack your own "AccountController" and have it accept an ID-token and sign-in that user.